# How to get data from mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql

I can't figure out how to get data from mySQL. This is my first attempt at using java to interact with mysql and its quiet confusing.

What I want this piece of code to do is go into my db find "table" then get the value of "column" where the persons' name = "name". Here's what I have

```
public boolean useProspawn(String column, String name ){
        //long time = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        //long prevTime = 0;

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        java.sql.Timestamp curTime = new java.sql.Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime());
        java.sql.Timestamp prevTime;
        long diff = 0;
        long duration = 0;
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = DatabaseConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT ? FROM accounts WHERE name = ?");
            ps.setString(1, column);
            ps.setString(2, name);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            prevTime = rs.getTimestamp(column);
            ps.close();
            rs.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error getting player's pro spawner times:"); //THIS IS THE ERROR THAT IS GETTING THROWN INTO THE CMD CONSOLE
            System.out.println(e);

            return false;
        }

       diff = curTime.getTime() - prevTime.getTime();
       duration = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diff);
       if (duration < 24){
           return false;
       } else {
           try {
            String psStatement = "UPDATE accounts SET ?=? WHERE name=?";
            PreparedStatement ps = DatabaseConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(psStatement);
            ps.setString(1, column);
            ps.setTimestamp(2, curTime);
            ps.setString(3,name);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            ps.close();
            rs.close();
            return true; // can use spawner
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error updating player's pro spawner times..");
            return false;
        }

       }

    }
```

I noticed that I'm getting the error at my "try/catch" statement because the only thing that is getting output in to cmd is the "error getting..." statement. Any ideas whats going on?

Comment: What is the error that you mean? compile error or runtime error and what is the error message?

Comment: Try adding `e.printStackTrace()` before the `System.out` and post the results

Comment: Based on the fact that you are passing the `column` name to the method, how can you guarantee the return type (column type)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I guess I can't be sure. How do I make sure of that? Iswanto San, the error happens in the try/catch statement, take a look at the code I posted.

Comment: Did you established the connection to the data base previously to make the query?

Comment: I'd drop the `column` variable to start with.  If you needed an "abstract" method, then I would use `getObject` and return that.  You would then need to cast the result.  You should be checking `rs.next()` to see if it returns `true` before trying to retrieve the value from the `ResultSet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious error is that the way you use the ResultSet for the select is not correct. Before you can get the first row values, you must call next first on the ResultSet.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
while (rs.next()) {
}
```

[JDBC Basic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)

Comment: A bit like `ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();` and `prevTime = rs.getTimestamp(column);` then?

Comment: Before you want to get any data from the resultset, you must have call rs.next() first. `ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();` `rs.next();` `prevTime = rs.getTimestamp(column);` - if you don't want a loop.

Comment: Tell the OP, not me ;)

Comment: does rs.next() happen by default? I never saw to do this explicitly?

Comment: you ALWAYS have to do that for select statement if you want to read some data... [ResultSet#next](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) **A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row**

Comment: Thank you! This got me a bit further! Now I'm just getting a sql syntax error: You have an error in
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''pro1'='2014-06-29 22:12:18' WHERE name='Hugo'
' at line 1 Any idea whats up?

Comment: Can you print the whole sql?